# Does Firebase analytics provide user’s area/city/state?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am planning to use firebase analytics in my android application.

I want to use it for statistical purposes such as knowing the geo-location of customers, their preferences etc.

Mainly I want user's geolocation (area, city, state, geo coordinate etc.)

Right now only country is visible as location.

How can I get other parameters of geolocation of any user ?

Comment: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317486

Comment: this can't be collected automatically i guess but can be logged into analytics from application

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I already checked this link.. and not able to found the one which I exactly need.. Please explain if I missed anything from this link..

Comment: @vikaskumar : how to do it from application, can you elaborate ?

Answer (score 4):

Reply from Firebase support team on my mail :

Currently, only data for country is available via Analytics console. However, we already have a feature request to add other geolocation data (region, city, etc.) in it. However, I can't give a definite timeline or details for when it will be available. I'll suggest to keep an eye out on our [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases) to get the latest Firebase updates.

Aside from that, you may want to [link your Firebase app to BigQuery](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765?hl=en) so you could access your raw analytics data which will then be exported to a corresponding BigQuery dataset on a daily basis. You can perform queries and do a custom analysis of your analytics data in there.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can view city data in Google Analytics > Demographics

[image: Google Analytics > Demographics > Users by City]

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer:**  You can't get user finer geolocation ( Except country name )

**Long Answer:**  Currently, you can't see finer granularity in Firebase Analytics. However, fine-grained granularity (Region and City) is available in BigQuery, so if you need that level of detail, you can link your Firebase app to BigQuery and access it there.

Let's assume if firebase provide latitude and longitude without device owner permission, then android compromising with user personal information which is against android guidelines and security concern, and hence it will also contradict with android marshmallow permission model(E.g Location Manifest Permission entry and Runtime permission)

Comment: My main focus is to get area, city, state of the user's so that it will be helpful for marketing or advertising purposes.. So lattitude longitude not needed necessarily.
But there could be the condition where I want to send the notification to the user's of a specific area/city. So how I will be able to implement this ?

Comment: Do you have any firebase reference link for the same?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-analytics-big-query, but its paid

Comment: UPDATE: Yes, you can get city data. Go to Google Analytics > Demographics

Answer (score 1):

Cites are available in the StreamView bookmark.

[image: Cites in the StreamView]

Regions and cites you will find after creating a new view in Google Analytics

[image: Region and cities]